# ReactJS - External JS Function "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In short, I'm trying to call an external JS function which my 3rd party required me to include, in order to use their API, but doesn't work as it supposed to.

From what I've read, I am supposed to use, for example, `window.extFn()` after including the external JS in my `index.html` which contains the `extFn()` like so

`<script src="https://example.com/external.js"></script>` <-- actually not like this, see update 2 as I imported the library locally

...and supposed to use it like how it was answered here: [Call external Javascript function from react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082047/call-external-javascript-function-from-react-components) regardless of whether the said function is inside a file or simply defined on `index.html` `<script>` section. This had worked on the JS file I created for testing this.

```
//File: test.js
function test() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

...imported the JS file with `script` tag like usual, and using `console.log(window.test())` in my React Component's `render()` returned `Hello`.

I tried moving the import to HTML head from body and vice-versa but the error I'm still getting is:

```
TypeError: window.extFn is not a function
QuickCheckout.render
....
  22 |    }
  23 | 
  24 |    render() {
> 25 |        window.extFn({
  26 |            
View compiled
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
```

And when I look into my browser console, for some reason I have (which seems to be the key problem)

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                                     external.js:1`

Tried `console.log(window.extFn)` and it returns `undefined`

So I think it might be possible that the said JS is the problem itself, but I'm at my wit's end with this. Meanwhile I had emailed my 3rd party support team, does anyone have any advice on this? Thank you very much.

UPDATE: Now my `test.js` file above, which had worked in my experiment, produces the `Unexpected token <` error as well in my console...

UPDATE 2: I apologize for your problems. But I actually imported the JS from local source due to having to port their library as they had jQuery 2 instead of 3.

`<script src="assets/js/external.js"></script>`

And to my dumbness, i forgot the trailing `/`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: make sure file include window.extFn function load before bundle files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the path of `external.js` is wrong, which returns a html file instead of js file

you can check what the request of `external.js` returns at the "network" tab in chrome dev-tool

Comment: And the funniest thing about this problem is, I opened that error only to see my own React's plain `index.html`. EDIT: Now my `test.js` also returns this html...

Comment: I think you are developing with webpack-dev-server with api proxy fallback, so when you try to include a file doesn't exist, it return the index.html file, so, make sure the path of external.js is correct

Comment: To my dumbness, I forgot to indicate it was a local import. Moreover, I forgot the trailing slash. Thanks for pointing out about pathings.

Answer (score 1):

At the begining of file, before the class definition, please add

```
let extFn = window.extFn
```

then inside of component,you can use it.

```
extFn()//call inside component
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as well, still the same error: `extFn is not a function`. I've edited my post to indicate that `console.log(window.extFn)` logged `undefined`

Comment: @ionizer please share the `extFn` defination from that lib.only signature is important.Is it enclosed in IIFE or closure?

Comment: I'm afraid to share here it as it's a 3rd party lib as I don't want to violate their regulations, but I don't know how to send a PM here. But it's really just a lot of function definitions which are valid, like my `test.js` file but with much more functions which contains jQuery AJAX.

Comment: @ionizer dont share the code,Just share with placeholder name and empty body contect with only that function.No need of lib or code sharing

Comment: @ionizer also check,network tab  under `js` tab is there such js file loading?

Comment: Actually, solved the problem and its due to pathing. I'm sorry for failing to indicate it was an import from a local source.