# Call Javascript function from react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one question because I'm not sure if that possible. I have ReactJS project that included some javascript functions.

I found solution to [call javascript function from react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082047/call-external-javascript-function-from-react-components) with **window** object but is it possible to call function from reactcomponents in javascript script?

For example I have definied function in React component. Is it possible to call that function in javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: *is it possible to call function from reactcomponents in javascript script?* Yes. That is completely possible. Create a module and import necessary component / function and call it

Comment: Of course, React is just a library for javascript. You can call builtin javascript function as well as user-defined global javascript function from your react code

Comment: any example or something? I'm working first time with this combination so please send me some example.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is.

```js
const App = () => <div>Hello world { externalFunction() }</div>;

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.querySelector( '#root' ) );
```

```html
<script>
  // Imagine this is an external source
  function externalFunction() {
    return Math.round( Math.random() * 100 );
  }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Resources**

- Some further readings on how to embed other script files
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script
- Also a really interesting article on what JS is or rather how it is working on a website
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript