# Call react component function from javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one question because I'm not sure if that possible. I have ReactJS project that included some javascript functions.

I found solution to [call javascript function from react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082047/call-external-javascript-function-from-react-components) with **window** object but is it possible to call function from reactcomponents in javascript script?

For example I have definied function in React component. Is it possible to call that function in javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to call a React component from a function? Can you provide the use case because the pattern doesn't seem correct and there's probably a better pattern for the use case

Comment: delete method is in react component. I'm working on click event in javascript function that need to call that delete method from react component.

Comment: What do you mean in javascript? you mean node? This doesnt sound like a good way of doing this.

Comment: Can you provide example code? To give context that will make it easier to understand the use case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function that is supposed to be used outside React application bundle should be exposed to global scope:

```
window.foo = () => { /* ... */ };
```

Then it can be accessed as such:

```
<script src="react-app-bundle.js"></script>
<script>
foo();
</script>
```

In case React application bundle is published as UMD module, it can export a function in entry point:

```
export const foo = () => { /* ... */ };
```

its namespace will be exposed to global scope when it's loaded via `<script>`:

```
<script src="react-app-bundle.js"></script>
<script>
ReactAppNamespace.foo();
</script>
```

This is the case for a lot of third-party React libraries, React itself exposes `React` global.

It's preferable to put all code that depends on React application internals to the application itself, so accessing globals is not needed.